# Is there a way to target an img with css once it's popped out into its own window?

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking for purely a CSS solution or a very short Javascript solution for the following problem:

There is an image on the page that you can click on and it pops out into its own window. The image is large enough it scales down to fill the height but instead it would be nice to see it at the 100% width of the browser window. Since the window really becomes a new page of its own without any strings attached to previous styling, what would be a good way to actually style that?

Comment: This question is too vague, please add more details to your post and some examples of what you've tried, what code you're using, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the window really becomes a new page of its own without any
>   strings attached to previous styling

If when the image opens up you want the previous styling to not affect it could use the "[inherit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit)" CSS property.

For example your markup could be something like:

```
<div class="popupImage">
    <img src="foo.png" />
</div>
```

And your css could be:

```
.popupImage {
    border-color: inherit;
    <other styles>: inherit;
}
.popupImage img {
    width: inherit;
    <other styles>: inherit;
}
```

You could also dynamically add css classes to the image container to overwrite styles when the image is clicked on with:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    this.addClass('preventStyles');
});
```